# jQuery element leaping on dblclick/blur

Tags: jquery, element

I've made following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Zxx9/

HTML:

```
<div class="question">
    <div class="questionLabel">
        <span class="questionTitle">How old are you?</span>
        <span class="hideCollapseQuestion">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="questionChoices">
        <div class="questionChoice">
            <div class="questionLetter">A</div>
            <div class="questionText">Over 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="questionChoice">
            <div class="questionLetter">A</div>
            <div class="questionText">Under 69</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
    <div class="questionLabel">
        <span class="questionTitle">Wat is your name?</span>
        <span class="hideCollapseQuestion">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="questionChoices">
        <div class="questionChoice">
            <div class="questionLetter">A</div>
            <div class="questionText">Ahmed</div>
        </div>
        <div class="questionChoice">
            <div class="questionLetter">A</div>
            <div class="questionText">John</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.question {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.questionTitle {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.questionChoices {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.questionChoice {
    display: table;
    padding: 2px;
}

.questionChoice > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.questionLetter {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #1b5e30;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.questionText {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.hideCollapseQuestion {
    float: right;
}​
```

JS:

```
$(".hideCollapseQuestion").each(function()
{
    $span = $(this);
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        var $questionChoices = $(this).parent().parent().children(".questionChoices");

        if ($questionChoices.css("display") === "none")
            $questionChoices.fadeIn();
        else
            $questionChoices.fadeOut();
    });
});

$(".questionTitle").each(function()
{
    $(this).dblclick(function()
    {
        onQuestionTitleChange($(this));
    });
});

function onQuestionTitleChange($title)
{
    $currentTitle = $title.text();
    $newInputField = $('<input type="text" value="' + $currentTitle + '" />');
    $title.replaceWith($newInputField);
    $newInputField.focus();

    $newInputField.blur(function()
    {
        $oldSpan = $('<span class="questionTitle">' + $newInputField.val() + '</span>');
        $newInputField.replaceWith($oldSpan);

        $oldSpan.dblclick(function()
        {
            onQuestionTitleChange($oldSpan);    
        });
    });
}​
```

My objective is to make question title editable on double click. Everything is ok at the beginning, but eg. if you edit first question, then edit second question and if you want edit first question again, it replaces second span with input [not first one as expected].

Please notice that I don't want to use ready plugins for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you have to do the follwoing on the last lines:

replace

```
$oldSpan.dblclick(function()
        {
            onQuestionTitleChange($oldSpan);    
        });
```

with

```
$oldSpan.dblclick(function()
                        {
                            onQuestionTitleChange($(this));    
                        });
```

Look at the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/3Zxx9/4/

Comment: That's right, thanks. Now I see that I've done the same binding dblClick for the first time :)

Comment: Even if that was the error, see my recommendations in my answer to improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the Question-Title you have set the dbl-click event on. That's ok, but better would be using jQuery's '.on' function properly:

```
$(".question").on('dblclick', '.questionTitle', function()
{
    onQuestionTitleChange($(this));
});
```

Then you don't have to reset the event handler further down.
**[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/h8PkF/1/)**

I also recommend you to just alter the visibility of the fields instead of recreating them over and over again...